# Create one file per date with only the file names that correspond to that date

Tags: bash, unix, awk, scripting

Given a single file with a list of file names (with the file paths), for example like:

```
input.txt (contents):
/2018/06/01/abc.txt
/2018/06/01/xyz.txt
/2018/06/02/abc.txt
/2018/06/02/xyz.txt
/2018/06/03/xyz.txt
/2018/06/03/abc.txt
/2018/06/01/ghi.txt
```

…
have to create one file per date with only the file names that correspond to that date
(all using standard Unix commands)
For e.g., 
expected output:

```
cat 2018-06-01.txt =>
/2018/06/01/abc.txt
/2018/06/01/xyz.txt
/2018/06/01/ghi.txt

cat 2018-06-02.txt =>
/2018/06/02/abc.txt
/2018/06/02/xyz.txt
```

Similarly for all other dates.

Comment: You can loop through this file and for each line extract the date part, and then append the line to the respective file. But note that if you follow this naive approach, it means that for every line from the input file, bash has to open the output file, do the appending, and close the output file. If you have a lot of lines, this might take long. For really long input files, I wouldn't use bash for this task.

Comment: @user1934428 i am trying to write a script for unix, can you help?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see some bash code in your question.

Comment: @VineetD : Post your code and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
{
    split($0,a,/[/.]/)                 # split record on chars ./
    f=a[2] "-" a[3] "-" a[4] ".txt"    # make filename 
    print >> f                         # print (appending) to file
    close(f)                           # close the file to preserve fds
}' input.txt
```

Files created:

```
$ ls
2018-06-01.txt
2018-06-02.txt
2018-06-03.txt
```

A file contents:

```
$ cat 2018-06-01.txt
/2018/06/01/abc.txt
/2018/06/01/xyz.txt
/2018/06/01/ghi.txt
```

Notice that there is no error checking.

Comment: Why use split and an array instead of just setting FS and using the fields?

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, it must've made sense a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Golden rule: Coffee first THEN keyboard... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too, a bit different approach from James sir, I am only closing the output file when its value is changing in Input_file(2nd, 3rd and 4th fields) and not equal to previous output file name(rather then closing it in every line). Also using `/` as a field separoator for lines.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="/"
  OFS="-"
}
{
  file=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4".txt"
}
prev!=file{
  close(prev)
  prev=file
}
{
  print >> (file)
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Vineet D, could you please try above once and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub() and internal open files control:

```
awk '{print > gensub("/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^.]+","\\1-\\2-\\3",1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
for i in `cat input.txt`
do
  y=`echo $i|cut -d "/" -f2`
  m=`echo $i|cut -d "/" -f3`
  d=`echo $i|cut -d "/" -f4`
  f_name=`echo "${y}-${m}-${d}.txt"`
  echo $i >>$f_name

done
```

**Edit** by Ed Morton (see comments below)

Just fixing the anti-patterns and bugs above but not actually improving it beyond that and still not suggesting this would be a reasonable approach:

```
#!/bin/env bash
set -e
while read -r i; do
  y=$(echo "$i"|cut -d '/' -f2)
  m=$(echo "$i"|cut -d '/' -f3)
  d=$(echo "$i"|cut -d '/' -f4)
  f_name="${y}-${m}-${d}.txt"
  echo "$i" >>"$f_name"

done < input.txt
```

Comment: That will corrupt your output in various weird and wonderful ways given various input values and it's extremely inefficient. Don't do it.

Comment: @EdMorton, he is just tring to lear bash I think, so simple example would be helpful to him. Just a thought

Comment: But you should literally never do this as it's full of bugs (e.g. unquoted variables), anti-patterns (e.g. `for i in cat...`), and deprecated constructs (backticks instead of `$(...)`) plus it's simply the wrong approach for a task like this anyway so it's not a useful example.

Comment: @Jeff once I was done it'd be a completely different answer though since this isn't an appropriate job for a shell loop (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) and the right approach (an awk script) is already posted. Tell you waht, I'll fix the issues so at least you can see how to write it IF a shell loop were appropriate for this.